# C# can not write to file ("being used by another process")?

Tags: c#, file, exception

I was hoping someone could explain to me why this is happening :)

When I use the code below it gives me the error "The process cannot access the file 'C:\test.txt' because it is being used by another process."

I'm very new to C# so I'm not sure what is going on, thanks in advance!

```
String fileNameBefore = @"C:\\test.txt";

public void output(String hex)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileNameBefore, true))
    {
        writer.Write(hex);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, *do* you have anything else (or possibly the same program) writing to the file? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: are you declaring or using writer variable anywhere else in your code..which references fileNameBefore

Comment: what context is this running in? say a website or a standalone app?

Comment: Maybe your process didn't shut down properly (ctrl alt del and kill it).  Or maybe you have that file open in an editor?

Comment: Use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to find out what has the file open, and why. (It may be *another* instance of your program!) Files are opened *exclusively* in Windows, even for "just reading", unless special "sharing" flags are set.

Answer (score 6):

Close the text file before you write to it. (Not in code...physically close the text file)

Comment: this could end up a very good guess, done exactly this myself :)

Comment: +1 This could very well be the reason, different programs operate differently: Notepad will keep the file locked. Wordpad will release the handle. (Or is it the other way about?) I would just mention [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), as it can be a very useful tool to find out *what* has the file open/locked.

Answer (score 4):

Under Windows Vista and Windows 7 the root of the system volume (usually C:) has a special protection: Programs have to run with full admin privileges to do anything other than creating or deleting non-system folders. Programs aren't allowed to create files there. Why it's saying the file is in use by another process? I'd expect another message, but I guess that's indeed the reason... Unless you've got some other program having that file opened and sufficient rights on the program whose code we see above.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a securityexception?

Comment: That's the point confusing me. But at the same time it's as well unlikely the file is opened exclusively by another process without noticing it.

Comment: It really isn't that unlikely :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the process is properly closed by checking in windows task manager and look for your process name, and if you find any end the processes manually by clicking the end process button and try it again.

If that doesn't work try moving the file path to a writable area such as the desktop because as mario says the root has a protection.

also check that the file is not hidden or write protected

Hope this helps regards
Tom